# "A single thing" as one and only thing?

Tags: formality

"the new design allows a single car to be used as both truck and bus"

"two people can use a single computer at the same time"

Can a single thing used like that to emphasize that only one thing is used (formally)? Or should I say "two people can use one computer at the same time"

Comment: To me, 'one computer' sounds as not being specific, i.e. not referring to 'the' computer in the context.

Further, for such scenarios, I would suggest using 'same' with 'simultaneously'. Eg. : Two people can use the same computer simultaneously. 

ALso, 'a car' is itself singular, so, it can be put as: "the new design allows a car to be used both as a truck and a bus.". Also, if the new design is specific to a car, then use 'the car' instead.

Comment: It's a common usage in all registers. The meaning is 'a single example of ...' not 'one particular'. Your first example sounds a little strange; "the new design allows a single vehicle to be used as either truck or bus, with only fairly simple modifications being necessary" sounds more reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with the defintion of *[single](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/single)*:

> adj.
>
> 1.- Not accompanied by another or others; solitary.
>
> 2.c. Consisting of one in number:
>   *She had but a single thought, which was to escape.*
>   *the freedictionary.com*

Continuing with the definition of *[one](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/one)*:

> adj.
>
> 1. Being a single entity, unit, object, or living being:
>      I ate one peach.
> 2. Being a single member or element of a group, category, or kind:   I'm just one player on the team.
>      *the freedictionary.com*

The word *one* is generally interchangeable with the expression *a single* in this context and many others, but because *one* has a broader definition, it allows for more ambiguity. In this context, the expression *a single* tends to **emphasize** the solitude more forcefully:

> ***A single*** vehicle that can be used as a car, a truck, and a bus, is probably a mediocre car, an inferior truck, and an inadequate bus.
>
> vs.
>
> ***One*** vehicle that can be used as a car, a truck, and a bus, is probably a mediocre car, an inferior truck, and an inadequate bus.